# chip sequencing

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, chip-seq

I understand the concepts of steps in Chip-seq up to DNA purification, but I don't get how one can then amplify the purified DNA samples that are once bound to the proteins.... Since sequence-specific primers are needed for qPCR, but you don't know where exactly the protein of interest binds to in the genome (that's why you do a chip-seq experiment), theoretically, how can you design primers to amplify?

[image: Specifically, I am referring to this graphical representation of the sites in ChIP-seq]

Specifically, I am referring to this graphical representation of the steps in ChIP-seq

Image source: https://compgenomr.github.io/book/measuring-protein-dna-interactions-with-chip-seq.html

Comment: This question could be reduced more generally to "how does whole-genome shotgun sequencing work?" The problem of translating a high-complexity mixture of naked DNA fragments to a sequencing library is shared by many techniques. I would strongly suggest reading more on the topic of library preparation. [Here](https://www.idtdna.com/pages/technology/next-generation-sequencing/library-preparation) is one resource.